# How to import resources from a library project?

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

I am currently developing an Android-App in Eclipse and trying to use a Library Project to access resources. I followed the description in [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html):
Under Project->Properties->Android I marked the Library Project as *is Library* and in the same setting windows, but for the other Android Project, I selected the Library Project as Reference.

What happens if I try to access a theme from the Library Project in the AndroidManifest.xml of my Android Project:

```
<activity android:name="com.bla.blub"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.HoloEverywhere">
```

=>

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.HoloEverywhere').
```

(The Library Project shows no errors and I see Generated Java Files in gen\ and the .jar-file together with the resources in bin\ )

What I also tried:

- in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

  `<uses-library android:name="com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere" />`
- clean, rebuild, restart Eclipse, restart computer, ...
- under Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries I added (and also removed again):

  - the Library Project's jar-file
  - the Library Project's gen-folder as Class-Folder

... without success. :/
Any ideas what I am missing? - It really seems to be a straight forward procedure and I already read lots of discussions about related problems, like:

[Android - Is it possible to create a custom library to use across several appilcations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828448/android-is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-library-to-use-across-several-appilc/1830774#1830774)
[When using an Android Library Project how do you reference xml resources properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846056/when-using-an-android-library-project-how-do-you-reference-xml-resources-properl)

... but I just can't get it running!

Hope someone out there has an idea! - Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not android style. Try to remove "android", leave just "@style"

Comment: OMG - You just saved my day! And it's that simple. - Unfortunately eclipse' auto-completion breaks down here. Thank you soo much!