# Library Error - Aviary - Android

Tags: android, layer, aviary

I am trying to plug the Aviary API into my app, and I am getting some weird errors.

To start, Aviary supplies a test-app to show how to implement the API and how it should work. This app runs fine, but I have it running on android 4.0.

My app is running on 2.2 and whenever I plug in the Android-Feather library, I get this error:

```
[2012-09-26 09:44:24 - The Fotolife App]     (skipping file '.DS_Store' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-26 09:44:24 - The Fotolife App]     (skipping file '.DS_Store' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[2012-09-26 09:44:24 - The Fotolife App] /Users/BradleyHoffman/Desktop/JavaPrograms/Android-Feather/res/values/styles.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layerType'.
```

Here is my manifest properties for my app:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

and here is the APIs manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

I would appreciate any help! THank you in advanced!

Comment: sorry, didn't know I was supposed to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides you a solution for fixing library error in aviary of Android

[When using an Android Library Project how do you reference xml resources properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846056/when-using-an-android-library-project-how-do-you-reference-xml-resources-properl)

Comment: In that link it says to prefix all resources. What does it mean by that?

Comment: I am not sure how to implement his method of how to correct the merging process.